# Firebase Rules for Cloud Firestore to limit maximum number of documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following use case..
I don't want to allow user control document limit in cloud firestore, I want to have firebase rule restrict it.

For eg. I have a products collection, user can do pagination (max=10) per page. if its browser side, user can easily change and get all the products list. Is there any settings or rules to control this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can protect this using the `query` property of the `request` object ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties)). Basically you can write a rule with a condition on the `limit`:

```
allow read: if request.query.limit != 10
```

The above rule will prevent the query from going through if the limit is not set to 10.

Comment: will this return first 10 if query limit > 10

Comment: No, it will prevent the query from executing at all.